# how to create an object from a vector insde a loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, object, vector

I'm in the situation where I would like to create an object from a character vector. For example:

```
v <- c("ind1_2015", "ind1_2016", "ind1_2017")

for (ind in v) {
 ind <- readRDS(paste0(ind, ".RDS"))
}
```

so at the end I would like to have 3 data frames, each one called ind1_2015, ind1_2016 and ind1_2017. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `assign`:

```
v <- c("ind1_2015", "ind1_2016", "ind1_2017")

for(ind in v) {
        
        assign(ind, data.frame(v = ind))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In R this is different from Python or similar. Initialize a named list but loop over the (numeric) indices.

```
for (i in seq_along(v)) {
  ind[[i]] <- readRDS(paste0(v[[i]], ".rds"))
}
ind
# $ind1_2015
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
# 
# $ind1_2016
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
# 
# $ind1_2017
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
```

Alternatively use `lapply`

```
ind <- lapply(setNames(v, v), \(x) readRDS(paste0(x, '.rds')))
```

To "unpack" the list use `list2env(ind, .GlobalEnv)` to get single data frames (not necessarily recommended).

---

*Data:*

```
ind1_2015 <- ind1_2016 <- ind1_2017 <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
lapply(c("ind1_2015", "ind1_2016", "ind1_2017"), \(x) saveRDS(get(x), paste0(x, '.rds')))
```

Answer (score 0):

`assign` can be used here, in this example resulting in three dataframes called `df_ind1_2015`, `df_ind1_2016`, and `df_ind1_2017` :

```
v <- c("ind1_2015", "ind1_2016", "ind1_2017")

for(ind in v) {
  value <- readRDS(paste0(ind, ".RDS"))
  assign(x = paste0("df_", ind), value = value)
}
```